# SSMS error Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio...package did not load correctly, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService not found

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I ran into a strange issue when I install SSMS v18.10 on my new work laptop (Win10 Pro Build 19042) with local Admin rights. I have tried both v18.10 and v18.9, uninstalled Extensions, etc. But none of them works.

The installation seems all good. But when launching SSMS, it prompts a warning message "The 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.... package did not load correctly".

[image: screenshot1]

After ignored this warning, when connection to our Azure SQL Database, it then prompts an error "Service 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService' not found (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio)"

[image: screenshot2]

I also noticed under "Help" menu, there're two "About" items., one is "About SQL Server Management Studio", and the other is "About...". On my old work laptop, I only got one "About..." in my SSMS. When clicking "About...", I got the same warning message as when launching SSMS.

[image: screenshot3]

When click ""About SQL Server Management Studio", I got below information.

[image: screenshot4]

Answer (score 1):

Relevant errors can be found by checking the activity log located at:

```
C:\Users\<username>\appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\AppEnv\15.0\ActivityLog.xml
```

When I encountered the same error as you, I checked that XML file and found this entry:

```xml
<entry>
  <record>61</record>
  <time>2022/08/10 03:18:52.795</time>
  <type>Error</type>
  <source>VisualStudio</source>
  <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91]Source: &apos;mscorlib&apos; Description: Could not find file &apos;C:\Users\[username]\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file &apos;C:\Users\[username]\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;File name: &apos;C:\Users\[username]\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.SetDefaultProjectOpenLocation()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.SetupInitialShellSettings()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)</description>
  <guid>{04401FF3-8B0F-4D2D-85EB-2A3542867A8B}</guid>
  <hr>80070002</hr>
  <errorinfo></errorinfo>
</entry>
```

The relevant part in the description being:

> Could not find file 'C:\Users[username]\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio';
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file `C:\Users[username]\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio'.

Creating the folder it could not find, `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio`, fixed the problem. Apparently during installation this folder could not be created for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try repairing SSMS via Apps & features (access by clicking windows button and typing app).  When open, look for  'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 18.10".  Select Uninstall.  It should give option for repairing.

Comment: Hi JMS, I tried Repair, but unfortunately I still have the same issue. Thanks.